# Running selenium webdriver test in Remote Desktop Connection is taking very long time

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remote-desktop

I am running a Selenium WebDriver test in the Remote Desktop using maven command. The test is taking very long time to load the URL and login into the site whereas when I try to run the same test in my local both URL loading and user Login where very quick. Can someone please tell me what would be the reason for that slowness.

Comment: Use PhantomJS or htmlunitdriver

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using Remote VM as UI tests host, has always been slower compared to local environment. Mainly because the dedicated VMs are missing the GPU and they try to render the requested browser(s) through the CPU. If you open your remote machine monitoring tool, most likely you'll see a lot of spikes when the browser launches. Similar to the one shown bellow.

[image: Firefox spike]

In order to optimize performance, you can employ headless execution (HtmlUnitDriver, PhantomJS) or [block certain content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128850/java-selenium-chrome-driver-disable-image-loading) from loading, like images, animations, videos etc. However when doing this, try to keep their placeholders.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. There are not many images on the website that I am working with. I will think about using HTMLUnitDriver.

Comment: Chrome actually allows you to run it with `--headless` flag. SO has a clear policy for helpful answers - if you think mine is to you, please upvote and mark as accepted.